# How to decode German characters(German umlauts) from the salesforce url?

Tags: apex, visualforce, url

I have an issue in Getting url parameters.Since i have german alphabets as values for parameters some of the characters are not decoded properly .

> my_vorname=Example_���my_name=Example_��my_strasse=Example_��dc_plz=100
>   this is how i get the parameters from salesforce.But from the client side i am getting proper values.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code as it is possible that issue is in it?

Comment: The URL is not controlled by salesforce code .A client application sends the URL along with their parameters to salesforce.So when i try to get the URL all values are malformed.

Comment: Do you know which encoding client application uses? If not, you could try using Daniel Ballinger's code snippet to try and decode string you get from client app using several common encodings and see if any of them produce correct output.

Answer (score 3):

When the German umlaut characters are sent on the query string they should be URL encoded for either UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. Then, as per Uwe's answer you can specify the `encodingScheme` with the second parameter in the [urlDecode](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlDecode) and [urlEncode](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlEncode) methods.

E.g. UTF-8 encoding where ä will be encoded as `%C3%A4`

```
string input = 'my_vorname=Example_ämy_name=Example_ämy_strasse=Example_ädc_plz=100';
String urlencoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input, 'UTF-8');
System.debug(urlencoded);
string decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(urlencoded, 'UTF-8');
System.debug(decoded);
System.assertEquals(input, decoded);
```

Output:
[image: UTF-8 German umlaut encoding on query string]

E.g. ISO-8859-1 encoding where ä will be encoded as `%E4`

```
string input = 'my_vorname=Example_ämy_name=Example_ämy_strasse=Example_ädc_plz=100';
String urlencoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input, 'ISO-8859-1');
System.debug(urlencoded);
string decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(urlencoded, 'ISO-8859-1');
System.debug(decoded);
System.assertEquals(input, decoded);
```

Output:
[image]

You could also specify UTF-16, which gives you and encoded value of `%FE%FF%00%E4` for ä.

---

What encoding were you using when you asked the question? In my version of chrome it appears as:

[image]

Firefox was the same and IE had square placeholder characters.

Comment: I dont have issue  in storing the german characters in string and decoding it .The issue is when you pass the german characters in URL and then try to decode you will not get the correct decoded value. I have raised this issue to salesforce support.

Comment: @ManojChandran I think you have an issue with encoding the German characters in the query string. My examples used strings to show how the values could be encoded and then decoded using various encoding schemes. The query string is exactly that, a string that is interpreted from the end of the URL. Can you add a screenshot of how the characters appear for you?

Comment: shall we discuss in private chat

Comment: @ManojChandran I'm not sure I'll be able to catch you in a private chat. Can you add a screenshot of the characters you are encoding?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with apex, have a look at the EncodingUtils class, there are two functions

- `urlDecode(String, String)`
- `urlEncode(String, String)`

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm

You can also do it with javascript, if you like.

Comment: I tried this but its not working